# SUBSTRING and IF statement

Tags: sql-server, query, substring, string-manipulation

I have `varchar` column, its name is column1 and has records like `111232435-0` and `1123443530`. The last digit is not always `0`; it can be `0-9`.

Some of them are digits with (`-`), other are digits. I want to change digits to digits with(`-`).

For example: `1123443530` -> change to -> `112344353-0`

Pseudo-code:

```
if record just be digit just update in column3
else
the last digit separate by (-)
and then record update in column3
```

In SQL Server 2012 and put this new record and records with (`-`) in new column.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative is to use [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ExampleValues') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ExampleValues

CREATE TABLE #ExampleValues (
    ExampleValue VARCHAR(100), 
    UpdatedValue VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #ExampleValues (ExampleValue)
VALUES
    ('112344353-0'),
    ('11443-8'),
    ('112344-9'),
    ('11234435348'),
    ('11234448712')

UPDATE T SET
    UpdatedValue = CASE 
        WHEN T.ExampleValue NOT LIKE '%-%'  -- If the literal does not contain a hyphen
            THEN STUFF(
                T.ExampleValue,             -- Put in the literal
                LEN(T.ExampleValue),        -- Just before the last character
                0,                          -- While replacing 0 characters ("stuffing" in between)
                '-')                        -- Place a hypen!
        ELSE
            T.ExampleValue END
FROM
    #ExampleValues AS T

SELECT
    T.ExampleValue,
    T.UpdatedValue
FROM
    #ExampleValues AS T
```

Result:

```
ExampleValue    UpdatedValue
112344353-0     112344353-0
11443-8         11443-8
112344-9        112344-9
11234435348     1123443534-8
11234448712     1123444871-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you are looking for

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(varname      VARCHAR(255),
                     newvarname   VARCHAR(255)
                    ); 

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT '111232435-0',NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT '1123443530',NULL;

UPDATE @table
   SET 
       newvarname = CASE
                       WHEN varname NOT LIKE '%-%' THEN 
                       LEFT(varname,LEN(varname)-1)+'-'+RIGHT(varname,1)
                       ELSE varname
                    END;


SELECT *
  FROM @table;
```

based on the above logic you can create the update statement.

**Edit 1**
Updated the code if the last digit can be any number and assuming that we need to only change the column which don't have a seperator `-`

Comment: Probably more efficient to use: `UPDATE table1 SET column1 = LEFT(column1,LEN(column1)-1)+'-'+RIGHT(column1,1) WHERE column1 LIKE '%-%' and `

Comment: @Lennart, yup that's right. I moved the `LIKE` to `CASE` since I think that's a new column and not on the same column. The OP says its a new column

Comment: Ah, I did not see that. I only read that he/she wanted to change the column